# How can DynamoDB's BatchWriteItem API call write more than 10MB of data, given that it can write a maximum of 25 items with 400KB/item?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

According to the official documentation: "A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)

But 25 put requests * 400KB per put request = 10MB. How then is the limit 16MB? Under what circumstances could the total ever exceed 10MB? Purely asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have also had the same doubt. Searched for this so much but found a decent explanation which I posted here (Don't know whether it is correct or not but I hope it gives you some intuition).

The 16MB limit applies to the request size - ie, the raw data going over the network.  Can be quite different from what is actually stored and metered as throughput.  I was able to hit this 16MB request size cap with a BatchWriteItem containing 25 PutItems of around 224kB

Also once head over to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html). This might help.

Comment: Exactly. You can write up to 10MB of actual data items, but there are overheads that make the request larger: An item with many tiny attributes has a lot of overhead in its JSON encoding, and perhaps more realistically, large blobs (the "B"ytes type) are encoded in JSON with base64 encoding, which enlarges the request size by 33%.

Comment: @NadavHar'El I believe the attribute names are actually counted against the data cap, just FYI. Good observation about base64 though.

Comment: @JamesShapiro you are right about the attribute names, but JSON can have other overheads - for example the number 42 is represented in JSON as {"N": "42"}, 11 bytes, presumably (?) larger than DynamoDB's internal encoding for this number.